# How can I make this macro work on selected text only? And can it be made to run faster?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to check certain documents to determine whether the number of insertions is < or >= 50% of the original text.
The macro I've cobbled together from various online sources does this quite well, and gives one of two message box messages depending on the text in question.

However, there are two issues:

1. the macro appears to run on the entire text, and I would like it to run only on the text the user manually selects prior to running the macro.
2. on certain files it hangs for a long time and sometimes crashes my PC.

How can I adjust the macro to ensure that it will run only on selected text? And can it be tweaked to make it run faster/be more robust/not crash my PC?

```
Sub RevMacro2()
  Dim lInsertsWords As Long
  Dim oRevision As Revision

    lInsertsWords = 0
    For Each oRevision In ActiveDocument.Revisions
        Select Case oRevision.Type
            Case wdRevisionInsert
                lInsertsWords = lInsertsWords + oRevision.Range.Words.Count
        End Select
    Next oRevision

n = ActiveDocument.Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
o = lInsertsWords
p = n / 2

Dim message As String
 If o < p Then
    message = "Blocks:" & vbTab & "60% Copy fee" & vbCr & _
    "Other:" & vbTab & "75% Copy fee"
 End If
 If o >= p Then
    message = "Blocks: 75% Copy fee" & vbCr & _
    "Other: 100% Copy fee" & vbCr
 End If
 MsgBox message

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an additional criterion, you might use something like:

```
Sub RevMacro()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long, r As Long
With Selection.Range
  n = .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords): r = .Revisions.Count
  For i = 1 To r
    With .Revisions(i)
      If .Type = wdRevisionInsert Then j = j + .Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
    End With
  Next
End With
If j / n < 0.5 Then 'less than 50%
  MsgBox "Blocks:" & vbTab & "60% Copy fee" & vbCr & _
  "Other:" & vbTab & "75% Copy fee"
ElseIf j / n < 0.75 Then  '50%+ but less than 75%
  MsgBox "Blocks: 75% Copy fee" & vbCr & _
    "Other: 90% Copy fee" & vbCr
Else '75%+
  MsgBox "Blocks: 90% Copy fee" & vbCr & _
    "Other: 100% Copy fee" & vbCr
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub RevMacro()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long, r As Long
With Selection.Range
  n = .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords) / 2: r = .Revisions.Count
  For i = 1 To r
    With .Revisions(i)
      If .Type = wdRevisionInsert Then j = j + .Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
    End With
  Next
End With
If j < n Then
  MsgBox "Blocks:" & vbTab & "60% Copy fee" & vbCr & _
    "Other:" & vbTab & "75% Copy fee"
Else
  MsgBox "Blocks: 75% Copy fee" & vbCr & _
    "Other: 100% Copy fee" & vbCr
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That looks to be absolutely perfect - thank you so much macropod (again - I believe you've helped me a great deal in the past too).

Comment: Hi again macropod - I have a follow-up question about the above macro. I've been asked to check if a further function could be added, namely: 

if the number of insertions in the selected text is > or = to 75%, a different message box be displayed, with the text "Greater than 75%"

Would you be able to help me out with a simple way to add this to the above code?

Many thanks in advance.